# Trying to open Request for permission in a popup

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the facebook C# SDK version 5.0.10. When I logon myself I don't understand why the "Request for Permission" interface is opened in a tab instead of in a new popup.

Here is my code:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
   { "response_type", "token" },
   { "display", "popup" },
   { "state", returnUrl },
   { "scope", scope.ToString() },
};

[...]

var loginUri = oAuthClient.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
```

Does anybody have an idea ?

Comment: Make sure your browser is not configured for opening new popups in a tab.. beyond that not sure (so I didn't make this an "answer")

Answer (score 0):

I also use C# SDK 5.0.10. I suggest to download the samples (FacebookSDK-5.0.10.0-41e55d6506e.src.zip) and check the samle called "CSASPNETFacebookApp".

I used the same technique of that sample and for me, the permissions don't open in a new tab or a new popup, but even better: in the same page. When you grant the permissions you will be automatically redirected to the App page you were trying to access. Very practical. With a few lines of code you can get the authentication working.

For the redirect, make sure to have in the web.config the handler:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

If you want the popup, then you have to use fbml (in the html/aspx page):

```
<fb:login-button onlogin="document.location.href=document.location.href;" perms="publish_stream">Grant Permissions</fb:login-button>
```

When you click the "Grant Permissions" button a popup with the permissions request will be opened.

Hope this helps.